# Excel UDF Function Not Updating

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make it so that my UDF function updates whenever its reference cells update.

Here's the code:

```
Function ConCatRange(CellBlock As Range) As String
Application.Volatile True
Dim cell As Range
Dim sbuf As String
    For Each cell In CellBlock
    On Error GoTo fred
    If Len(cell.Text) > 1 Then sbuf = sbuf & cell.Text & Chr(10)
        Next
    ConCatRange = Left(sbuf, Len(sbuf) - 1)
fred:
End Function
```

When reference cells are blank, however, it will not show #VALUE! - This is what I want. Instead, it will just not update and keep the data that was last populating the cell.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you do not have TEXTJOIN?

Comment: In addition to @GarysStudent suggestion, `Application.Volatile` is unnecessary.  The UDF will update whenever the referenced cells are updated; and having that there will force it to recalculate unneccesarily.

Comment: I do not have textjoin, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see `#VALUE!` just remove the `On Error` statement.  This will allow the `Left()` function to report its failure.

Comment: Throwing an error is different than returning an error to the cell like a built-in UDF does.

Comment: @HackSlash The end result will be the same in that `#VALUE` will be returned by the formula to the cell containing the formula.

Comment: This does not achieve the desired result. The function will still fail to update automatically unless I click into the cell and hit "enter" manually.

Comment: @BobbyZullo  Have you set the calculation mode to ***Automatic*** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Function ConCatRange(CellBlock As Range) As String
Application.Volatile True
Dim cell As Range
Dim sbuf As String
    For Each cell In CellBlock
    On Error GoTo exitErr
    If Len(cell.Text) = 0 Then GoTo exitErr
    If Len(cell.Text) > 1 Then sbuf = sbuf & cell.Text & Chr(10)
        Next
    ConCatRange = Left(sbuf, Len(sbuf) - 1)
    Exit Function
exitErr:
    ConCatRange = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Within the loop, you check for a Text length of 0 and if it finds one, returns CVErr(xlErrValue) - also known as "#VALUE!"

Comment: This does not achieve the desired result. The function will still fail to update automatically unless I click into the cell and hit "enter" manually.